# Sequelize target postgres 8

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have been using sequelize for a while on the project. Since now, nothing was deployed on the server and I thought it would be just "npm install" and run the application. But I got this strange error on the server:

```
{ [SequelizeDatabaseError: error: syntax error at or near "NOT"]
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  message: 'error: syntax error at or near "NOT"',
  parent:
   { [error: syntax error at or near "NOT"]
     name: 'error',
     length: 81,
     severity: 'ERROR',
     code: '42601',
     detail: undefined,
     hint: undefined,
     position: '17',
     internalPosition: undefined,
     internalQuery: undefined,
     where: undefined,
     file: 'scan.l',
     line: '911',
     routine: 'base_yyerror',
     sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "adapters" ("id"   SERIAL , "adapter_number" VARCHAR(255), "password" VARCHAR(255), "last_connect" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, "adaman_version" INTEGER, "adaap_version" INTEGER, "created_at" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updated_at" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));' }
```

I found this error in issues and the guy there said it just needs upgrade of postgres to 9. Unfortunately all the systems on deployment server are using postgres 8 and upgrade will not be avaliable soon.

Is there any way in sequelize to specify what postgres version I am using, or what sequelize version that I should use?

Thanks

Comment: Hm, didn't know that pg8 does not support this :-/ I wonder if you could go with migrations in that case ?

Answer (score 1):

It seemns that `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS` is not supported in postgres 8. I searched around a bit, but achieving the same behaviour seems to be quite involved.

`IF NOT EXISTS` is added to table creation when you do `sync({ force: false })` in sequelize (or leave out `force` completely). I would recommend you to either call `sync({ force: true })`, **which will drop and recreate the tables**; or simply not call sync at all, and rely on migrations as @sdepold mentioned

Comment: Thank you. Will try this and post after.

Comment: Tested and it seems like it does not work. Statement is still the same, so is error with { force: true }

Comment: @Gelidus I am having the same problem, and upgrading postgres to v9 is not an option. Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @SoichiHayashi no, the functionality was not implemented in the library that day and I am really not sure if its now. We updated all the systems to Postgres9